# Java - Cancelling Futures

Tags: java, future, executorservice, callable, cancellation

I have a problem with cancelling my `Future`s. First let me explain the scenario. I am making a program which generates images based on certain parameters. These images are "pannable" with the mouse. What I mean by this is that the user can take and drag the image along to reveal a different section (like one normally would do). Every time the user pans a new image must be calculated. This can take a while for certain parameters and therefore the following is done.

1. (If the program is idle.) When an updated image is required a low resolution image is calculated to give the user instant feedback. When this has been done the program starts on a high resolution image.
2. If there are images that have been submitted to the `ThreadPool` (but not yet completed) they are cancelled (see below for details). After this we treat the pan as per point 1.

This works great if I make a low amount of changes (but still too many to calculate every image). If I make two rapid changes for instance the program quickly calculates a low resolution image and starts on a high resolution one. Before it has finished the high resolution one a new change is made by the user. This triggers a cancellation of the high resolution image then starts a new low resolution one and finally a new high resolution one. This works.

The problems arise when I grab the image preview and start panning like a madman. Now the futures are cancelled sporadically and as I stop panning I end up with a large stockpile of threads attempting to calculate high resolution images that should have been cancelled. What might cause this? I have tried to write some code below to explain my problem as well.

```
public class Test {

    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);

    private ArrayList<Future<WritableImage>> highResFutureList = new ArrayList<Future<WritableImage>>();
    private ArrayList<Future<WritableImage>> lowResFutureList = new ArrayList<Future<WritableImage>>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        xAndYProperty.addListener(//ChangeListener that calls updateLowResImage());
    }

    public void updateLowResImage() {
        if(lowResFutureList.size() != 0) {
            for(Future<WritableImage> future : lowResFutureList) {
                //I do not want low res images that have begun calculation to cancel, thus false.
                System.out.println("Attempting low res cancel: " + fure.cancel(false));
            }
        }
        if(highResFutureList.size() != 0) {
            for(Future<WritableImage> future : highResFutureList) {
                //I do want high res images that have begun calculation to cancel, thus true.
                System.out.println("Attempting high res cancel: " + future.cancel(true));
            }
        }

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Future<WritableImage> future = threadPool.submit(getImageTask(lowResolution, lowResolution));
                lowResFutureList.add(future);
                try {
                    setImage(future.get());
                    System.out.println("Low res Future completed.");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("Low resolution Future cancelled.");
                } finally {
                    lowResFutureList.remove(future);
                }
            }
        }).start();

        int resolution = (int) resolution.getValue();
        if(resolution > lowResolution) {        
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    updateHighResImage(resolution);
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

    public void updateHighResImage(int resolution) {
        EnhancedCallable<WritableImage> task = getImageTask(resolution, resolution);
        task.setDescription("Updating " + name);
        Future<WritableImage> future = threadPool.submit(task);
        highResFutureList.add(future);
        try {
            setImage(future.get());
            System.out.println("High res Future completed.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("High resolution Future cancelled.");
        } finally {
            highResFutureList.remove(future);
        }
    }

    public Callable<WritableImage> getImageTask(int width, int height) {
        return new EnhancedCallable<WritableImage>("Generating " + name) {
            @Override
            public WritableImage call() {

                //Making image in nested for loop...
                for(int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
                    for(int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                        //Calculating pixel values...

                        if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                            System.out.println("INTERRUPTED!");
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return image;
            }
        };  
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I should also mention that I am very new tho `Futures` and everything related so go easy on me.

Comment: Is it the best way? Why not do those simple edits on client side (may be on small resolutuon image) and pass final image coordinates to server. I am pretty sure people will unknowably abuse your api.

Comment: updateHighResImage(resolution); get call at the end of updateLowResImage so if you it can be add and not cancel in the time that pass. for example  say you call updateLowResImage 100 time and "if(resolution > lowResolution) {        
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    updateHighResImage(resolution);
                }
            }).start();
        }" not start at all at time of cancelling, they all run